# How to extend the current translator in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, extends

I have **two** Sphinx extensions that need to extend the `html` translator. So in each of them I have:

```
class Translator(HTML5Translator):
    def depart_caption(self, node): # Extend whatever there...
        return super().depart_caption(node)

def setup(app):
    app.set_translator('html', Translator)
    return {
        'version': '0.1',
        'parallel_read_safe': True,
        'parallel_write_safe': True,
    }
```

Unfortunately this is not supported by Sphinx because I get an error: `Translator was already defined`.

What is the possible alternative?

Comment: Give the two subclasses different names, like Translator1 and Translator2?

Comment: It is two different extensions, located in two different files. It does not matter if they have the same name

Comment: I wish I could even get to that error (docutils/sphinx has been the most painful framework I've integrated with in recent memory)